# M1 mac cannot run jboss/keycloak docker image

Tags: macos, docker, jboss, keycloak, apple-m1

Switched to m1 mac a week ago and I cannot get my application up and running with docker because of the jboss/keycloak image not working as expected. Getting the following message from the container when trying to access localhost:8080

```
12:08:12,456 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-5) MSC000001: Failed to start service org.wildfly.network.interface.private: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service org.wildfly.network.interface.private: WFLYSRV0082: failed to resolve interface private

12:08:12,526 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("interface" => "private")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"org.wildfly.network.interface.private" => "WFLYSRV0082: failed to resolve interface private"}}

12:08:13,463 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0026: Keycloak 12.0.4 (WildFly Core 13.0.3.Final) started (with errors) in 20826ms - Started 483 of 925 services (54 services failed or missing dependencies, 684 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

Tried with all image versions and all behave the same. Has anyone managed to run this image without issues? Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using this image, I am now able to startup keycloak. https://hub.docker.com/r/wizzn/keycloak

Comment: I tried it. Works after setting docker experimental feature 'Use new virtualization framework' (Big Sur instead of hypervisor).

Comment: This image is more recent now https://hub.docker.com/r/sleighzy/keycloak

Comment: this is the correct answer. complete steps:
[STEP1] docker pull wizzn/keycloak:14 [STEP2] docker run --rm -p 9080:8080 -e KEYCLOAK_USER=admin -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin wizzn/keycloak:14 [STEP3] http://localhost:9080/auth/

there you go.

Comment: the image is no anymore available in docker hub !

Answer (score 35):

Also you can build the keycloak docker image locally, I was able to start keycloak after doing that. Here are the steps I follow;

1. Clone Keycloak containers repository: git clone git@github.com:keycloak/keycloak-containers.git
2. Open server directory (cd keycloak-containers/server)
3. Checkout at desired version, eg. git checkout 12.0.4
4. Build docker image docker build -t jboss/keycloak:12.0.4 .
5. Run Keycloak docker run --rm -p 9080:8080 -e KEYCLOAK_USER=admin -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin jboss/keycloak:12.0.4

[image]

Comment: This is a better solution than depending on third party images. All steps can be easily scripted.

Comment: Created my own docker image here. Running well on M1 https://hub.docker.com/r/codingpuss/keycloak-silicon

Answer (score 4):

For Keycloak 16, docker 20.10 and docker-compose 1.29, this image works flawlessly: https://hub.docker.com/r/sleighzy/keycloak - as suggested by @zakjan.

A service like:

```
  keycloak:
    image: sleighzy/keycloak
    environment:
      ... your Keycloak config
```

Should be enough to get up and running.

Answer (score 3):

I'm on an m1 and I ran this and it worked.

```
docker run --platform=linux/amd64 -p 8080:8080 -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:17.0.0 start-dev
```

I merely add `--platform=linux/amd64` to their docker command I found in https://www.keycloak.org/getting-started/getting-started-docker

Comment: This helps only with the initial `WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested`, but Keycloak still fails to start.

Answer (score 1):

The location for building a quarkus version of keycloak has changed, so this method will not work anymore for any major releases greater than 16. But the following script will. Just save it as an sh. file and execute it in your terminal. By enabling the last line, this will also directly start an instance of Keycloak.
The version number can be changed, but this is only tested for M1 chips and version 17.0.0.

```
VERSION=17.0.0 # set version here

cd /tmp
git clone git@github.com:keycloak/keycloak.git
cd keycloak/quarkus/container
git checkout $VERSION
docker build -t "quarkus-keycloak:$VERSION" .
#docker run -p 8080:8080 -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin "quarkus-keycloak:$VERSION" start-dev --http-relative-path /auth
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an update to this issue - images for AMD64 and ARM64 architectures are now available and can be found here: https://quay.io/repository/keycloak/keycloak?tab=tags.

Ref the discussions in Github (https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-containers/issues/341 and https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/8825).

Answer (score 0):

jboss/keycloak not supported arm64 for now.
But you can use that image on docker hub: mihaibob/keycloak

> https://hub.docker.com/r/mihaibob/keycloak

I'm using this and haven't difference.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31186070)

Answer (score -1):

I don't have a mac but I just started working with jboss/keycloak lately and have been able to get it to start.

Essentially what I did (assuming docker is installed):

```
docker pull jboss/keycloak:16.1.0 
docker run --env-file targetDB.txt -p 8080:8080 jboss/keycloak:16.1.0
```

Might have to do those commands with `sudo`

This pulls the jboss/keycloak image from docker hub and then it runs it exposing the port 8080 within the container to the host machine.  It also uses the environment variables in the .txt file (which contains info on the database endpoint you wish to connect keycloak to to persist data).

If you don't specify `--env-file <text file>` I believe keycloak uses its default h2 Database which isn't the best.

I have my local jboss/keycloak pointing to an postgres db I have in an AWS RDS environment, so the contents of the targetDB.txt for me is:

```
DB_VENDOR=postgres
DB_ADDR=<my postgres aws rds endpoint>:5432
DB_DATABASE=<name of the database>
DB_USER=<db username to connect to postgres instance>
DB_PASSWORD=<password associated with db username to connect>
```

If I'm not mistaken the name of the Database in DB_DATABASE field must already exist.  So you'll need to create that before running the docker run command.

After you do the docker run command above and the logs show it starting up you should be able to access the keycloak admin console on your local browser:

`http://localhost:8080/auth`

If this is the first time you're running keycloak you have to create a master/admin user before you can log in.

To add a master user, run these commands (while your keycloak is already running):

`docker exec <container id or container name> /opt/jboss/keycloak/bin/add-user-keycloak.sh -u <USERNAME> -p <PASSWORD>`

then you need to restart your keycloak container:

`docker restart <container id or container name>`

Again you might have to do those commands with `sudo`.

After thats done, go back to your local web browser `http://localhost:8080/auth` and you can now access the login page and actually login with the username and password you created above.